# Recover and decrypt email app password

Tags: ipad, email, security, password, keychain

My boss gave me his iPad and tasked me to get his Yahoo password that was in the default mail app. He made the account 15 years ago, and we both have tried all the recovery options (security questions are forgotten, backup email is no longer accessible). Additionally the passwords are not stored in the safari saved passwords

What I *do* know is the format of the password ( x number of symbols then y number of numbers etc )

I understand that passwords are stored in the keychain and are encrypted.

**Should I:**

Jailbreak the iPad and get the db file for the keychain and decrypt it using something like hashcat (while knowing the format of the password)?

Make an encrypted backup via iTunes and get the db that way?

Or is there a better way to recover the password?

**Note:** I only have Windows available to me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- buy a Mac from Apple
- set it up, use the same iCloud account/Apple ID as on the iPad
- enable iCloud Keychain syncing using the iPad keychain as a starting point
- access password via Keychain application
- disable iCloud on Mac
- return Mac to Apple and get refund

PS: please check the applicable return policy for your country first

Comment: So there was a mac laying around I can use. This will allow me to see the plain text password of the email I am trying to access?

Comment: You need to log into the same iCloud account on both devices and enable Keychain syncing. If the passwort is in the keychain you can access it in plaintext through the Keychain application on the Mac

Comment: Note that iCloud keychain syncing will copy passwords both directions - from iPad to Mac, and from Mac to iPad. If this is an existing Mac with its own memorized passwords (that you probably don't want on the iPad), you can  create a new user account on the Mac (in System Preferences -> Users & Groups), then log into the new account and sync its (empty) keychain with the iPad.

Comment: It seems the yahoo account is using Oath, so the actual password cannot be recovered. Thanks anyways!